# vue.js multiple image upload does not render

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, upload

I am trying to create multiple image upload with vue.js . Everything seems works well. However when I add image, html does not render me list of thumbnail of images I have chosen. What is more, I get strange output in my console.

Here is my html code:

```
<v-layout row>
  <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
     <v-btn raised class="primary" @click="onPickImageList">Upload Image</v-btn>
     <input
       type="file"
       style="display: none"
       ref="fileInputList"
       accept="image/*"
       multiple
       @change="onImageListPicked">
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>

<v-layout row valid-v-if="imageList">
  <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3 v-bind="image in imageUrlList" >
       <img :src="image" height="150">
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

Here is my Script code:

```
data () {
return {
  imageList: [],
  imageUrlList: []
}
```

}

```
onPickImageList () {
  this.$refs.fileInputList.click()
},
onImageListPicked (event) {
  let selectedFiles = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files 
  this.imageList = []
  Array.prototype.push.apply(this.imageList, selectedFiles)
  if (!this.imageList.length) {
    return
  }
  this.createImage(this.imageList)
},
createImage (file) {
  for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader()
    // var vm = this
    fileReader.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.imageUrlList.push(fileReader.result)
      console.log(this.imageUrlList)
    })
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[i])
    this.imageList = file[i]
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

What I should fix, to render list of thumbnail of my chosen images?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of using the filereader, choose URL.createObjectURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `v-bind="image in imageUrlList"` you should use a `v-for="image in imageUrlList"`,

Also I do not see the reason for using `Array.prototype.push.apply(...)`

With vue you should avoid doing that because you will not trigger the reactive data to change the DOM.

Simply do :

```
this.imageList.push(selectedFiles);
```

Comment: Yes, it works thx, silly mistakes, as I am new with vue :) what is more the last 2 columns should be like this:
fileReader.readAsDataURL(selectedFiles[i])
this.imageList = selectedFiles[i]

selectedFiles are from previous function